# Adding Version number as well as Document ID Value to a Sharepoint Online Word document

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, version, footer

I've read many articles on this now but it seems the the {version} tag it's no longer possible to add the {version} tag as an option in a content type information management policy in the  label format field in sharepoint online. In addition, it looks like the label field is no longer shown as an option in Word Quick Parts any more (unlike the document id value). Anyone know how I can do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I can create a {Version} label in Information Management Policy settings in SharePoint Online library.

[image]

And I can also insert the label in Word after open document from SharePoint Online library.

[image]

Comment: That's really strange as I dont get those options.  Where are you creating those policies please?

Comment: I create a policy via library settings->Information management policy settings->click the relevant content type->tick the enable label option.

Comment: Ah I did try that but I get a message stating "You cannot change policy settings for this content type because it inherited the settings from its parent content type or a site level content type. To change these policy settings, change the settings for the parent of this content type. " so I went back to the root site and tried tghe same there under Web Designer Galleries > Site Content Types and selected Document there and that's where I get the "The label reference, Version, could not be found." message when I put "{Version}" in the Label Format box.